# Adding TableAdapter throw me a failed to to open connection

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, datatable, dataadapter

I try to create a TableAdapter in visual studio, I pass all steps of the wizard and when I end, it tries to create the TableAdapter and give me an error. It's my first time trying to create a TableAdapter so I may miss something really obvious.

My setup

- Visual Studio 2010
- My instance is on `\\VMDEVCIAQ\NMPUTIL`
- My connection string is `Provider=SQLNCLI10;Data Source=VMDEVCIAQ\NMPUTIL;Persist Security Info=True;Password=Secret;User ID=Secret;Initial Catalog=NMPUTIL`

Error message

`"Failed to open a connexion to the database, error 26 error locating the server/instance specified"`

What I tried

```
- portqry.exe -n VMDEVCIAQ -p UDP -e 1434
```

and it gave me a positive answer. So it's not a firewall problem or SQL Browser service not running.

I know the connection string work since in the connection wizard it says connection successful.

Any idea why visual studio is being mean to me ?

Cheers

Comment: Is your SQL instance named 'NMPUTIL' as well as your database

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same issue. Have you found a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, I ended up recreating the dataset (XSD file). I copied the objects from the broken dataset to the new one, using the dataset designer interface and all was well.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you are using a "Named Instance" to connect to SQL Server, be sure to check if the SQL Browser service is running (`[Start] -> "services.msc"`) on the same computer that the SQL Server is on.

Also make sure the server has both the SQLBrowser executable and that the UDP Port 1434 is open - a firewall often may be blocking access.

Finally, use Visual Studio to reconfigure the connection string found in the project settings. I, for instance, moved away from the SQL Server Authentication with username and password to the "Default Instance" then tested the connection, and saved my connection string.

Also ensure the connection string is correct in the DataSet/TableAdapter properties. As that would render all the above useless. It is that string that is the connection string Visual Studio is trying to connect to.

Because of caching, after any changes to the connection string, restart Visual Studio. I can't tell you which of the above (if any at all) is the fix to this problem. But I can assure you that after you do fix the problem restarting Visual Studio is needed, even with VS2013.